# Why Field Accessibility Check is broken in a Managed Package?

Tags: managed-package, permissions, failing-tests, crud, fls

my code has a centralised class which is responsible for all DML operations. This class before inserting / updating / deleting a record is checking:

1, if the object is accessible for the current user

2, if the fields are available.

This works in the non managed package, but is broken when I'm trying to create a managed package.

For example, the code below throws the error ONLY when I'm trying to package the code (this is a check on a custom object's custom field).

```
if (Transaction__c.Status__c.getDescribe().isUpdateable() != true) {
    throw new SObjectAccessException('Payment360: You can\'t access this field.' );
}
```

Any ideas what can be the problem? My understanding is that the tests are running on behalf of sysadmin user (if not specified otherwise), so they should have access to all fields.

Comment: Are you adding the Profile Settings when creating the package? I know that the Sys Admin is supposed to have full access, but this might be the cause of your problem. As you are trying to create a managed package, you might as well try to create a profile that has access to everything and test this out.

Comment: It's a bit of a cop out, but you could add a `&& !Test.isRunningTest()` to the end of the condition to avoid the exception. I don't think `System.runAs` will help you here, as it won't affect field level permissions.

Comment: I have used this in my packaged code and it worked fine for me. Can you add exactly what error do you see? also screen shot of error will help us.

Comment: Thanks so for everybody -- `System.runAs` did not help (however, I'm using permission sets, not profiles, so I'll give a shot again). @DanielBallinger in my current solution is also avoiding this in test-context, but still a little bit worried if the security review team will be happy  as well with this :p